# Bootstrap: How to align Image tag and two <p> tags in a bootstrap div?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to bootstrap.I want to place an image tag and two

elements inside a div so that image tag and

elements should be in side by side.

code:

```
     <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="../Content/Images/App/image1.png" style="height:50px; float:left" /> 
        <p>Employee ID</p>
        <p>EmployeeName</p>         
        </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
<div class="col-xs-2"></div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Expected Output:

I want Image and employee details parallely.(Employee id and Employee Name one below the other)

can anyone help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css');
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="../Content/Images/App/image1.png" style="height:50px;"/> 
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <p>Employee ID</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <p>EmployeeName</p>         
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi,i m splitting the viewport into 6 col-xs-2.I have edited my question.Thank you